# Angular2 multiple router-outlet in the same template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Is it possible to have multiple router-outlet in the same template?

If yes then how to configure the routes?

I am using angular2 beta.

Comment: What do you exactly want to implement? Could sub routes fit your needs? See this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#child-router.

Comment: i need to build an application that uses multiple session (tabs)  each session has the same content (like the browser tabs).

Comment: check the talk from the developer of the router, to see what is currently possible -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4 IF I remember well there are child routes and auxiliary routes.

Answer (score 66):

yes you can, but you need to use aux routing.
you will need to give a name to your router-outlet:

```ts
<router-outlet name="auxPathName"></router-outlet>
```

and setup your route config:

```ts
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/', name: 'RetularPath', component: OneComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {aux:'/auxRoute', name: 'AuxPath', component: SecondComponent}
])
```

Check out this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JsZbuR?p=preview), and also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4&feature=youtu.be).

---

Update for RC.5
Aux routes has changed a bit:
in your router outlet use a name:

```
<router-outlet name="aux">
```

In your router config:

```
{path: '/auxRouter', component: secondComponentComponent, outlet: 'aux'}
```

Comment: by the way, as of January 2016, according to this resource we should not use aux just yet, since it is not ready https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5027#issuecomment-169464546

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am using angular2 beta. i tried to define the aux route :  
{ aux: '/edit-entity/:id', name: 'EditEntity', component: EditEntityComponent }

when i call it doesn't work:

 this._router.navigate(['/', ['EditEntity'], { id: id }]);

Comment: make sure you are including the complete route in the navigate section, not relative to your component.

Comment: if you want a relative route use ['./routeToYourComponent'] notice the dot before the slash

Comment: Update: as of May 2016, Angular2 just released their RC (release candidate) and now Aux routes are supposed to work.

Comment: @TomerAlmog any idea as how they are supposed to work? Theres no 'aux' memeber on the configs routes  (but theres an 'outlet')

Comment: @zedd you need to use the new router bundle, not the router-deprecated to use aux

Comment: 1 vote for update answer to RC5. Angular2 change so fast.

Comment: Discussion of auxilliary routes in the linked video starts at 14:25.

Answer (score 59):

You can have multiple router-outlet in same template by configuring your router and providing name to your router-outlet, you can achieve this as follows.

**Advantage of below approach is thats you can avoid dirty looking URL with it. eg: /home(aux:login) etc.**

Assuming on load you are bootstraping appComponent.

app.component.html

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="page-header">
        //first outlet to load required component
        <router-outlet name='child1'></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        //second outlet to load required component
        <router-outlet name='child2'></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add following to your router.

```
{
    path: 'home',  // you can keep it empty if you do not want /home
    component: 'appComponent',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: childOneComponent,
            outlet: 'child1'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: childTwoComponent,
            outlet: 'child2'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when /home is loaded appComponent will get load with allocated template, then angular router will check the route and load the children component in specified router outlet on the basis of name.

Like above you can configure your router to have multiple router-outlet in same route.

Comment: I tried your approach, but it does not work.

Comment: @FilipWitkowski you really need to pay attention to the routes, you must have the children's path as an empty string i.e. "" otherwise the router will need you to provide which outlet you want to target (or nothing will work)

Answer (score 21):

Aux routes syntax has changed with the new RC.3 router.

There are some known issues with aux routes but basic support is available.

You can define routes to show components in a named `<router-outlet>`

Route config

```
{path: 'chat', component: ChatCmp, outlet: 'aux'}
```

Named router outlet

```
<router-outlet name="aux">
```

Navigate aux routes

```
this._router.navigateByUrl("/crisis-center(aux:chat;open=true)");
```

It seems navigating aux routes from routerLink is not yet supported

```
<a [routerLink]="'/team/3(aux:/chat;open=true)'">Test</a>

<a [routerLink]="['/team/3', {outlets: {aux: 'chat'}}]">c</a>
```

*Not tried myself yet*

See also <s>[Angular2 router in one component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962955/angular2-router-in-one-component/37967806#37967806)</s>

RC.5 routerLink DSL (same as `createUrlTree` parameter) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#createUrlTree-anchor

Comment: Is this supposed to work in RC5? I haven't managed to get it working. Looking at the source code for the router I cant find any "@Input() name" either.

Comment: `@Input()` name is a property of the `RouterOutlet` class. I have to check the aux route path syntax for routerLink.

Comment: The current syntax seems to be `<a [routerLink]="['/team/3', {outlets: {aux: 'chat'}}]">c</a>`

Comment: Please look at this question and see if you manage to help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142396/angular-2-rc5-router-named-outlets

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer After looking at your answer - I think i'm missing something - is it possible to remove AUX routes after visiting them  via routerLink ? ( not via code ) . [_I've tried your answer in this simple plnkr without success. The aux route just won't reomove_](https://plnkr.co/edit/NaSnjDvXcW8zxpYuG04Y?p=preview)

Comment: I never really tried aux routes because I always run into some bugs. I haven't tried since several months and many things were fixed since then, but I'm not familiar with aux routes and afraid I'm not able to help you. There might be other questions with answers to that problem.

Answer (score 16):

`<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { list:['streams'], details:['parties'] } }]">Link</a>`

```
<div id="list">
    <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div id="details">
    <router-outlet name="details"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`

```
 {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminStreamsComponent, 
        outlet:'list'
      },
      {
        path: 'stream/:id',
        component: AdminStreamComponent,
        outlet:'details'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can as said by @tomer above. i want to add some point to @tomer answer.

- firstly you need to provide name to the `router-outlet` where you want to load the second routing view in your view. (aux routing angular2.)
- In angular2 routing few important points are here.

  - path or aux (requires exactly one of these to give the path you have to show as the url).
  - component, loader, redirectTo (requires exactly one of these, which component you want to load on routing)
  - name or as (optional) (requires exactly one of these, the name which specify at the time of routerLink)
  - data (optional, whatever you want to send with the routing that you have to get using routerParams at the receiver end.)

for more info read out [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteDefinition-interface.html) and [here.](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/AuxRoute-class.html)

```ts
import {RouteConfig, AuxRoute} from 'angular2/router';
@RouteConfig([
  new AuxRoute({path: '/home', component: HomeCmp})
])
class MyApp {}
```

Comment: Both your links are broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use multiple router outlets in the same template with `ngIf` condition. But you can use it in the way shown below:

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
  <span>loading true</span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!loading">
  <span>loading false</span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  </div>

  <ng-template #template>
    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: IMPORTANT: This causes components to initialize twice!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be another (rather hacky) way to reuse the router-outlet in one template. This answer is intendend for informational purposes only and the techniques used here should probably not be used in production.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-twice-with-events

The router-outlet is wrapped by an ng-template. The template is updated by listening to events of the router. On every event the template is swapped and re-swapped with an empty placeholder. Without this "swapping" the template would not be updated.

This most definetly is not a recommended approach though, since the whole swapping of two templates seems a bit hacky.

**in the controller:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      console.log(routerEvent);
      this.myTemplateRef = this.trigger;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.myTemplateRef = this.template;
      }, 0);
    });
  }
```

**in the template:**

```
<div class="would-be-visible-on-mobile-only">
  This would be the mobile-layout with a router-outlet (inside a template): 
  <br>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplateRef"></ng-container>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="would-be-visible-on-desktop-only">
  This would be the desktop-layout with a router-outlet (inside a template): 
  <br>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplateRef"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #template>
    <br>
    This is my counter: {{counter}}
    inside the template, the router-outlet should follow
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #trigger>
  template to trigger changes...
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me and pretty straight-forward and simple.

```html
<div *ngIf="authenticated">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!authenticated">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #template>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This does not make any sense. Please review your answer.

Comment: this code is actually legit, we have something similar live in our production code. however it is using one router-outlet, not multiple