# Set parent markup from nested child route component

Tags: angular

I would like all of my routes' components to be nested in a BaseLayout component. This is easy for simple examples using `router-outlet`, where the entire child component is injected into the router-outlet. Is it possible define multiple places for a child to inject content into the parent? Similar to how named ng-content blocks work? I would like a child route component to be able to define content for header, main, and footer.

Answer (score 0):

The new [docs for routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) states:

> A template may hold exactly one unnamed . The router
>   supports multiple named outlets, a feature we'll cover in future.

So to make it work you'd add a `name` attribute on your `<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>` and use that in your route config:

```
{path: '/chat', component: ChatCmp, outlet: 'aux'}
```

See more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096837/2972

Comment: I don't think aux routes is what I want. I'd like to do something like:

    `{path: '', component: BaseLayoutComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
    ]}`

and have the HomeComponent template define multiple content blocks which are injected into the BaseLayout template.

Comment: Then I think you need the deprecated routing, which won't last very long.

Comment: Our whole project already uses the latest router, so we won't revert to the deprecated one. Is there a way to do this with aux routes? It seems like it's solving a different problem.

Comment: It probably is, but I'm not sure exactly how. It does seem like they try to explain something similar in the new docs.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very clear in the current docs. I'll live with some markup duplication for now and hopefully docs get updated with more info soon. thx