# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'listproducts'

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am trying to redirect to another component on a button click inside the component using the router.navigate() method. I am using a secondary router outlet. But every time I am getting this

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'listproducts'
```

app-routing-module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: "home", 
    component: HomeComponent ,
    children: [
      { path: 'additem', component: AdditemComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" },
      { path: 'bookitem', component: BookitemComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" },
      { path: 'listproducts', component: ListProductsComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" },
      { path: 'listorders', component: ListOrdersComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet" },
      { path: 'viewcart', component: ViewCartComponent, outlet: "mainOutlet"}
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

component:

```
CreateOrder(customer: Customer){
    <<do something>>
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {mainOutlet: 'listproducts'}}]);
}
```

There are questions with similar title but all are related to redirecting from html template.

Comment: Shouldn’t you use your router link to navigate to home/listproducts

Comment: Yes, I am using that in my html template like this: <a mat-button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {mainOutlet: 'listproducts'}}]">Products</a>      But in this case, there is another button, which needs to do some task and then, redirect to this component.

Comment: The createOrder() method you are calling, in what component is that? What is the full url path at the time you are calling this method?

Comment: @SnorreDan I am calling it from the ViewCartComponent.

Comment: refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517100/angular-2-router-named-router-outlet-navigation-from-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517100/angular-2-router-named-router-outlet-navigation-from-code)