# Can we have multiple <router-outlet> angular2+?

Tags: angular

If it is possible to have multiple router outlets, I don't have any working code but assume I have login page in parent `<router-outlet>` in `AppComponent`. Once logged in I have to show `MyHomeComponent` in the parent `<router-outlet>`. Now, assume that, in `MyHomeComponent` I want a child `<router-outlet>` in which I want to show `inbox` messages, `outbox` messages, `starred` messages as user clicks on `Inbox`, `Outbox` and `Starred` links. Please help me to find an answer to this question

**AppComponent** 
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,

**HomeComponent**

```
<a routerLink="/xyz">Inbox</a>
<a routerLink="/abc">Outbox</a>
<router-outlet name='outlet1'></router-outlet>
```

My routes paths

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'user', children:[ 
         { path: ':name',children:[ 
               {path:'abc', component: InboxComponent, outlet: 'outlet1' },                                      
               {path:'xyz', component: OutboxComponent, outlet:'outlet1' } 
    ] }]}, 
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have one primary `<router-outlet>` for every route and additional named `<router-outlet name="abc">`s. The routes addressing these named outlets are called auxiliary routes. These routes are reflected in the URL within `()` like `/crisis-center(aux:chat;open=true)"`

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html
- [Angular2 multiple router-outlet in the same template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template/38096837#38096837)

Comment: I did some thing like, Showed login page in primary outlet and after login I displayed Home Page in the same outlet. Now, I want to show inbox and outbox messages in child router outlet but If i use as you said, the primary outlet is replaced by child outlet

Comment: I don't know aux routes very well myself but without seeing the code that demonstrates what you tried I have don't see a way to diagnose the problem at all.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Actually I don't know what the `outlet: 'xxx'` in the route configuration does or if it does anything. What I have seen is components created in named outlets when a routerLink or `router.navigate()` passes an `{outlets: ...}` object like shown in examples in some of the linked docs in my answer.