# Angular 2 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isActivated' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

If I return to the same routing path it show an error

"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isActivated' of undefined".

But not show at first time. can any one help me ?

## routing

```ts
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
    {
        path: 'home', loadChildren: './apps/home/home.module#HomeModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        resolve: {
            crisis: NavigarionResolve
        }
    }
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

## Component

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService }            from '../main/service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-app',
  templateUrl: 'apps/home/view/home.component.html',
  providers: [AuthService]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  loaded: boolean = false;
  title = 'Customer Management Home';
  slogan = 'Hi ...Home ';
  views: Object[] = [];
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.views = [
      {
        name: "My Account",
        description: "Edit my account information",
        icon: "assignment ind"
      },
      {
        name: "Potential dates",
        description: "Find your soulmate!",
        icon: "pets"
      }
    ];

  }
  logout() {
    this._authService.logout().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

## Navigarion

```
 this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

Comment: could you please add your underlying component code?

Comment: I edit my post please see it

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, it seems to have cropped up out of nowhere, I've undone all my changes that I can see since it was last working and it seems to have stuck around.... I can visit any any route fine, but on trying to navigate to any other component after loading the site using the router it throws the OP's exception.

Comment: Please add module and authguard code too.

Comment: AuthGuard code seems to be missing

Comment: `isActivated` is nowhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Why don't you do a search over your project for "isActivated".

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm getting the same error, and isActivated is nowhere in my project. I've submitted an edit with my stacktrace to the question. It comes from angular router

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the full stack trace. There has to be an `isActivated` somewhere and we have to find where.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer line 2807 of router.umd.js v3.0.1 in `PreActivation.prototype.deactivateOutletMap` is where it throws from for me.

Comment: Seems there is something wrong with the router-outlets. I guess this requires a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: For different route has different template with different 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>, 

like one route has <router-outlet name="footer" ></router-outlet> and other has <router-outlet name="left" ></router-outlet> and

when I go from one route to other with outlet compatible routing then the error occur.

Comment: I've never used multiple router outlets, but do you not need to use aux on the second router? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was a second instance of the app being loaded. 
This was caused by an invalid templateUrl within a "control" component.

I moved a spinner component I have from `app/components/client/spinner.component` to `app/components/shared/spinner.component` but forgot to update the templateUrl.
This meant that my spinner was loading up inside my other components with the wrong html. I had used the correct path for the component in `module.ts`, so it wasn't throwing any build errors, but when it couldn't find the spinner.component.html, mvc6 was returning the default index page, so it tried to load up the entire app from inside the component. This inner app was then being removed once the spinner was removed as my content had loaded.

I don't fully understand it, but it appears the router was having some sort of conflict due to the app being loaded again from inside itself.
In my case, I was lucky enough to notice that my app was glitching, so I paused javascript during the glitchy part and scanned the html, and noticed there was a `<html>` tag inside my spinner.

**Try setting a breakpoint inside your app.component** class and seeing if it gets hit twice, or running `document.getElementsByTagName("my-app")` (or whatever your app.component is called) in the console and if you have more than 1 element returned you should be able to debug the problem from there. In my case this only showed while the spinner was showing, so if you have components coming and going on your page, try breaking on each one show/hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is discussed at github, looks like the component dependency issue, the following link may help you:

[Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519)