# Using multiple routers in an angular app (NOT in single component or in child routes)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my angular app, I have 3 components.

1. First is a `login` component.
2. Upon successful login, the user goes to `dashboard` component.
3. `Dashboard` component has two tabs namely for, `add` and `list` components.

My problem is with `router-outlet`.

The `login` and `dashboard` components are shown in main `router-outlet` which is *not named*.
The `dashboard` component has another `router-outlet`. This one is named as follows.

```
<router-outlet name='app'></router-outlet>
```

**Problem**

When a user clicks on a tab, say `add`, then `AddComponent` should be shown in `router-outlet` named `app`, but instead, I'm getting following error,

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'add'↵Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'add'↵    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError

When I removed `outlet` property from route definition, then the `AddComponent` is shown in *unnamed* `router-outlet`, overriding `dashboard` component.

**Routes defined**

```
[
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate:[ LoginGuard ]
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddComponent,
    outlet: 'app'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent,
    outlet: 'app'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

**Note**
I have tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template) but getting above mentioned error.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CUUC7yQCeem6ORBQUpdy?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui, Thank you for the solution.