# angular2 Router-outlet wont work after logged in

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

When im logged in, and navigate to otherpage or login i get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'customComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'customComponent'
```

But when im not logged in,  navigating works.

I also noticed that if i remove one of the router-outlets the navigation will work. Lets say i remove the router-outlet in loggedin, the navigation within user.username will work as normal.

How come?
How can i make it work as it should? if not logged in, show router outlet there, else if im online, show it somewhere else?

Code:

```
 <div *ngIf="user.username">
   <a routerLink="/murder" routerLinkActive="active">Murder</a>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>

    <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="loggedin == false">
   <a routerLink="/murder" routerLinkActive="active">Murder</a>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>

// other things
    <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:

i made the router-outlet in login to:

```
 <router-outlet name="regular"></router-outlet>
```

and outside:

```
        <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
```

and changed my routing:

```
   path: 'murder',
              component: MurderComponent,
              outlet: 'regular'
```

but when i navigate i get:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'murder'
```

how come?

full code routing:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([

              {
                  path: 'login',
                  component: LoginhandlerComponent,
                  outlet: 'aux'

              },

          {
              path: 'murder',
              component: MurderComponent,
              outlet: 'regular'

          },


          ]

      )
```

Comment: if you will use multiple router-outlet you need to give a name for <router-outlet> tags. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template

Comment: i did that, didnt i?

Comment: sorry i didn't see you updated the code.I have looked again but i couldn't catch the point caused error. but i wonder where is your routerLink which routes to 'murder'.

Comment: updated @BlackEagle, the murder is changed from other to murder in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add outlet to your router link. Try like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'regular': 'murder'}}]" routerLinkActive="active">Murder</a>
```

Comment: if i do that. i need also to do:

     {
              path: '',
              component: LoginhandlerComponent,
              outlet: 'outside',
          },

to handle when its not a path.

but when im inside i cant use regular.
is there a way to check if user is logged in before assigning ?

Comment: You need to move also router-outlet (that without name) outside of ngIf statement.