# Angular Material SideNav Content Strategy

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a standard sidenav layout along the lines of this

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

   <mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>

   <router-outlet></router-outlet>

   <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav position="end"></mat-sidenav>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I want to use that second sidenav as a content area.

On this project, all of the active routes are simply Components with a Canvas Region and some basic information about the "Experiment". Perhaps some basic form sliders or controls.

```
<div>
   Some Content
<div>
<canvas>
</canvas>
```

Basically I want the content div to go in the second sidenav container. Only the Canvas is a child of the actual component visually.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

   <mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>

   <router-outlet>
        <canvas-component>
             <canvas></canvas>
        </canvas-component>
   </router-outlet>

   <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav position="end">
       <div>
            Some Content
       <div>
   </mat-sidenav>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This seems crazy, i don't think a child should be reaching out this way and depending on a parents structure. I get that. The inverse, of having the Component add a sidenav would be much better but the sidenav has to belong to a sidenav container and so this is still outside the boundaries of the component.

So what is the best strategy instead? I can't seem to get my head around it.  Would you see this as 2 components , requiring 2 outer outlets and needing a shared service so they can talk to each other?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

1. Only the "canvas" sidenav should have the `<router-outlet>`.
2. If the "canvas" sidenav depends on any other component for its data, you need to extract that logic into a separate service. This way, your "canvas" sidenav could independently get its data from it.
3. If you still need two different outlets in your template, you should use [aux routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642273/3612903), BUT - if your main content area (the homepage) is static - you don't need a route to display it, use the "home" component in your template and keep the `<router-outlet>` only in your "canvas" sidenav

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: I updated my question. So would you split my `canvas-component` into 2 components? `canvas-component` and `canvas-component-info`. Then I would need 2 router outlets? One for the main region of the page, and one for the sidenav? Then I need a Service so that these can talk to each other?

Comment: 1) Not sure splitting the canvas component is necessary.

2) If you need 2 different outlets in your template you shoud use [aux routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642273/3612903), but if your main content area (the homepage) is static - you don't need a route to display it, simply use the "home" component in your template and keep the `outlet` in your "canvas" sidenav.

BTW, you still have 2 `<mat-sidenav>` elements inside 1 `<mat-sidenav-container>` in your example. Each should have it's own `<mat-sidenav-container>` wrapper. As far as I know sidenavs aren't supposed to be nested.

Comment: Thanks DotBot! I will take a look when I am home and report back! One thing is that you can have 2 sidenavs, but no more than 2. https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Comment: Thank you again @DotBot!  Aux routing is the rabbit hole I needed to find. I have decided to create a Module for each of my Canvas Experiments. Each experiment module will have a `CanvasComponent`, `InfoComponent` a `Service` for them to communicate. The Aux will send both Components to their respective outlets and they may communicate via the service.  I really appreciate your thoughts on this as I was stuck cold.

Comment: Sounds like a plan :) sure thing @Clark!