# Angular 8 parent layout with many router-outlets

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular parent project app that defines a configurable layout and imports components from other applications to use that layout. The layout has a left side panel, center content area, right side panel, and a footer.

In addition, each app will be able to stand alone.

Each imported app will have its own customized components for those four sections. I was thinking that the components would be imported into the parent apps and be swapped out in the main layout's router outlets.

Four router outlets seems like a lot to have on one page. However, I would like to define a shared layout as most of these pages will be structured the same and I don't want to update each app if a small global change comes down. Is having four router outlets bad practice and would there be a best practice way to handle these?

Edit

I know how to create multiple router outlets. My question is about best practices when trying to merge 5 Angular apps into one with configurable layout. Also I want to keep the source code separate.

Comment: Explain..........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 multiple router-outlet in the same template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template)

Comment: We have 5 Angular applications that each stand alone as their own web app. We want to have a shared app that brings them into one main project by importing the desired components (we don't want to move any code into the new parent project). We also want to use a standard layout for each app in the parent project. The apps should be able to run both as stand alone apps and inside the shared app. Again, I want to have 5 different Angular projects, import some of their content into a shared project with a shared layout and allow the users to navigate between apps.

Comment: I know how to create router outlets. My question is about best practices when trying to create a configurable layout while using 4 router outlets.