# Angular puts route content as sibling element of primary <router-outlet> element

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

When I load a route to the primary router-outlet, Angular creates a sibling element to show the content. For example, my route "events" is loaded like this in the DOM:

[image]

Is this correct? Or should the `<app-events>` element be inside `<router-outlet>`?

The website does look like it should in the browser.

Comment: Yes. This is how it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Angular generate the route elements after the `router-outlet` element.

From Angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) about the `RouterOutlet`:

> Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state.

Also, You can use multiple routes as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template).

Comment: Actually, that quote seems to suggest that the content should be inside the <router-outlet> element.

Comment: I don't see much difference about the location of the dynamic content. For example, if you got 2 routes, so the content would be - option 1 as sibling one content at the time, or option 2 - inside each router element. I think that for clarity option 2 is better...