# Angular 9 routerLink to 2 outlets at the same time

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-router, angular-routerlink

1. How can I have routerLink link to both main router-outlet and secondary (sidebar) router-outlet?

I have:

```
<a [routerLink]="['', {outlets: {sidebar: 'filters' }}]">FILTERS</a>
<a [routerLink]="['home']">HOME</a>
```

When I am trying to combine this into one link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['home', {outlets: {sidebar: 'filters' }}]">HOME</a>
```

it's poining to /home/(sidebar:filters) - which is broken link.

Here is my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ttnrvd).

2. Is there any way to have two route-outlets load their components with one link without having this ugly url?
   I tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42204114/1351452, but it does not seem to be working.
3. Maybe for sidebar tied to specific route (or set of routes) should I use ngIf directive, that I would compare to route to chose right component?

Comment: Have you tried something like `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'home', sidebar: 'filters' } }]"` ?