# Load remote modules into a shell App and display them side by side

Tags: angular, widget, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm trying to implement a micro frontend architecture in my Angular application using Module Federation.

The shell application loads remote modules from Mfe1 and Mfe2. I've successfully exposed and loaded these modules in the shell app. However, I now want to display these modules side by side in the shell app.

Additionally, I want to enable remote routing, allowing navigation from a list to details within the widget itself without affecting the shell routing.

Comment: This question is far too vague. Please be more specific and possibly provide code examples that pertain to a specific question.

Comment: What do you mean by "widgets"? I suppose your shell app is loading Angular components. So when you say "widgets", in which format do you want the shell to load those components?

Comment: @Giancarlo it is not widgets, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672611/how-to-load-two-different-apps-side-by-side-using-angular-and-module-federation

Comment: If you want to load your federated components side by side without using router, then check this article out. I hope this is what you want. Here the link https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular-2/

Comment: Thank you Giancarlo Sotelo. I've successfully loaded components side by side and also in another way loaded modules side by side using named outlets. Now, my next challenge is to create navigation(routing) for each application section inside.